# streaming an archive that is being composed from other streams

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka-stream, akka-http

Say I have a lot of files in s3 and depending on user request I want starting streaming an archive that is being built from other s3 file streams. Is it possible to implement stream flow like below? What archive does provides asyc composing and streaming?

```
+----------+ (async download)   +-------+
| S3 file1 |------------------->|       |
+----------+                    |       | stream to user over HTTP
                                |Archive| ------------------------> Usser
+----------+ (async download)   |       |
| S3 file1 |------------------->|       |
+----------+                    +-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Alpakka provides an S3 Connector which allows you to use S3 as a source and sink in Akka applications.

you can use that along with Akka Http to stream S3 data on HTTP.

https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html

Comment: I'm not the OP but I believe that the hardest part (and the one that is being asked for) is such as archive format that you can write to it files coming asynchronously from several concurrent streams without a need to buffer whole files and write them sequentially. AFAIK standard things like ZIP do not support such modes. And I don't think that your answer is of any help for this issue.